# fwrite overwrite without closing the connection

Tags: php, fopen

How to overwrite a text using fopen

```
$data = 'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH';
$data2 = 'JJJJJJJJJJJJJJ';

$F = fopen('tbbbb.txt','w');
fwrite($F,$data);
fwrite($F,$data2);
fclose($F);
```

I want output should be

"JJJJJJJJJJJJJJ"

in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) function:

```
fwrite($F,$data);
fseek($F, 0);
fwrite($F,$data2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rewind` to return to the beginning of the file.

```
fwrite($F,$data);
rewind($F);
fwrite($F,$data2);
```

The resulting file contents will be:

```
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJH
```

because overwriting the beginning of the file doesn't replace what comes after it. You can call:

```
ftruncate($F, count($data2));
```

to set the file length.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` will always write where the cursor position is and navigate the cursor to next line. So when you write first string, it will write to first line and navigate the cursor to next line. SO current cursor position is on second line. So if you want to overwrite a particular line you will have to `seek` to that line.

```
fseek($F, <byte_position>);
fwrite($F, <string>);
```

Comment: fseek takes a byte position, not a line number.

Answer (score -1):

Use [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', $data);
echo file_get_contents('file.txt'); // HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
file_put_contents('file.txt', $data2);
echo file_get_contents('file.txt'); // JJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
```

Comment: He said he doesn't want to close the connection. `file_put_contents()` opens and closes the connection.